# UILocalNotification with repeat-once behaviour like in Messages App

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, uilocalnotification

I have simple `UILocalNotification`:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.alertBody = @"Message";
notification.alertAction = @"Action";
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.category = kCategoryIdentifier;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

Is it possible, to repeat notification once, for example after two minutes? I want behaviour exacly, like in Messages app.

I have tried to set repeatInterval property of notification object, but:

- Notification will be presented to user every two minutes, not repeated only once
- System shows to user new notification, not repeat the old one. User see two notifications, one with timestamp 2 minutes after another.

Which is not what I've expected.

Also, because of second reason, I don't want to schedule two separate notifications.

Edit: In my app time when something happend is very important. Because of that, in lock screen, when notification is repeated, **I want user to know that is something that happend earlier, not in time when notification arrives.** So repeated notification should have timestamp of first notification.

Comment: you want after 2 mint  repeat local notification

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set repeatInterval.

See documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval)

> The calendar interval at which to reschedule the notification.
>
> Declaration SWIFT 
> `var repeatInterval: NSCalendarUnit` 
> OBJECTIVE-C
>   `@property(nonatomic) NSCalendarUnit repeatInterval`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for NSCalendarUnitMinute system will repeat notification every minute, not once. Also timestamp of notifcation will suggest to user that's a new notification, not notification that happend earlier and it's repeated for some reason.

Comment: Yeah but you can hold a counter for reapeat count of each notifications, when will raise, if counter for activeNotification is > 1, cancel it.

Comment: thanks, but still, the timestamp issue is really important to me. In lock screen, when i'm repeating notification I want user to know, that is something that happend earlier, not in time when notification arrives.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
 localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Message";
        localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
        localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;

        NSLog(@"LocalNotif.soundName %@",localNotif.soundName);
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            localNotif.fireDate = [repeatAlarm dateByAddingTimeInterval:120*i];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
        }
```

Comment: You create 20 notifications. He asked how to repeat one to raise 2 times.